# Android Nougat 504 installation error

Tags: android

Our App Kidstriangle User installation from google play store works fine on Android 4,5,6 but we always get 504 error when install on Any Android 7
1. Already tried clear cache, clear data, login/out from store.

Any idea why this is specific to Android 7 only.
We are using google-play-service GCM:7.0.0 (used for notification) to get maximum comparability is that can be one of the reason?
1. Using latest Android studio and Graddle with targetSDK 25 and compiled with 25.0.3, minSDK 16

Comment: What does 504 mean?

Comment: Did you opt-in to Google Play App Signing? We're experiencing the same problem after opting in.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is if you are using android 2.2.2
1. release apk are aleardy algned avoid aligning them again
2. avoid/uncheck v12 full signature while generating the signed apk

Google issue: 504 is generic error that comes after app is being downloaded from google play store and before installation starts. this error code typically is being used to show the issue with google play service. but google is using this error code for non-obvious reason as well that makes user more confusing.

So advice if you are having error code: 504 while installing app from google play store use above two recipe to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed 504 error for me

So at the time of generating build "Generate Signed APK -> Signature Versions: Select only V1(Jar Signature)"